# QGIS count with relation_aggregate if a condition is met (similar to Excel's COUNTIF function)

Tags: qgis

I am working on a file with 2 related layers: **Developments** and **Projects** (1 to many relationship). The purpose is to track renewable projects in my country where one "Development" can contain several "Projects". This way I can track that Development *Langa* has 3 projects: *Langa Solar Energy Facility*, *Langa Wind Energy Facility* and *Thezi-Langa Solar Energy Facility*.

I have a calculated field in the **Developments** layer that returns the number of projects in each development by using the following expression:

```
relation_aggregate( 
    relation:= 'Projects', 
    aggregate:= 'count', 
    expression:= "fid"
)
```

I would like to add 2 extra fields that will do the same, but technology specific: one will count solar projects and the other will count wind projects according to the "technology_id" in the **Projects** layer. In the example described above for the Langa development, it would return 2 for the calculated field for solar and 1 for the calculated field for wind. Essentially, I want the functionality of the COUNTIF function of MS Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `relation_aggregate` appears to have no `filter` parameter, you can adapt your expression like so:

###### QGIS >=3.28

```sql
array_count(
    relation_aggregate(
        relation:='Projects',
        aggregate:='array_agg',   -- make array of values returned by the `expression` parameter
        expression:="technology"  -- the field name containing the technology attribute
    ),
    'solar'                       -- the attribute value of the name/code of the technology to be counted
)
```

It aggregates all `technology`'s into an array (per relation), and then counts all instances of `solar` in that array.

###### QGIS <=3.26

```sql
array_length(
    array_filter(
        relation_aggregate(
            'Projects',
            'array_agg',
            "technology"
        ),
        @element='solar'
    )
)
```

It aggregates all `technology`'s into an array (per relation), filters that array for instances of `solar` only, and then gets the length.

You can repeat the expression for your second field but change `solar` for `wind`.

###### Output *before* the count

*note, screenshots are for QGIS >=3.28*

Shown here are the technologies in the array for Development A:

[image]

###### Output with the count included

Shown here is the number of `solar` projects for Development A:

[image]

###### Final result

[image]

###### Multiple conditions

To count instances using multiple conditions, the `expression` parameter of `relation_aggregate` can be set as an array, resulting in an array of arrays. The `array_count` function can then be used to count arrays that meet the conditions (or use of `array_filter` and `array_length` as above):

```sql
array_count(
    relation_aggregate(
            'Projects',
            'array_agg',
            array("technology", "authorised")
    ),
    array('solar', 'TRUE')
)
```

Comment: Amazing! Works great, thanks! I had to update to 3.28 as the array_count function is not available in earlier software releases.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I hadn't realised it was a recent addition. I will add the QGIS version to my answer.

Comment: Using `array_length` with `array_filter` should work for versions prior to the `array_count` function beig added. When I get time I will offer an alternative expression.

Comment: Is there a similar array_count function that will count projects that meet more than 1 condition? i.e. number of projects where "technology" = solar AND "authorized" = TRUE?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Superstar! Thanks 

Comment: Imagine additional "solar_sum" and "wind_sum" attributes for the developments and a "size" attribute for projects. Imagine in the example above that Langa Solar Energy Facility is 75MW, Langa Wind Energy Facility is 100MW and Thezi-Langa Solar Energy Facility is 50MW in size.

Is there a way for a development to group the sum of the sizes of its projects in a way that "solar_sum" = 125MW and "wind_sum" = 100MW?